# textfield becomeFirstResponder gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS code

Tags: ios, uipickerview, textfield

I have two textfields; on tap of one I open a `pickerView` and on tap of next textfield I want to remove above opened picker from view and open keyboard but using `[textfield becomeFirst Responder]` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` textfield delegate method I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS code crash.

The code is as such:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField == earningCodeTextField) {
    [self dismissKeyboard];
    [self showPickerView];
    return NO;
}
else if (textField == codeTextField) {
    [self hidePickerView];
    [codeTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `[codeTextField becomeFirstResponder];` in the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` will call the be `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` again and this might cause the error. You should not call `[codeTextField becomeFirstResponder];` because it is already becoming the first responder.

Comment: Yes in this scenario textFieldShouldBeginEditing is called iteratively. I implemented i in textfieldShouldReturn and it worked!!